# How to remove NAs from a matrix which results in a square format?

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have a square matrix that is:

```r
> dim(matrix)
[1] 5777 5777
```

However there are a total of 178 NAs in the whole matrix. More than one NA can appear in each row. Therefore, there are 82 rows with NAs.

I can see where the NAs are by doing this:

```r
which(is.na(LD_matrix), arr.ind=TRUE)
                                  row  col
rs997007:18566990:C:G             1403    1
rs66492148:18888055:AAT:A         2340    1
1:18293758:T:TTCA                  585   25
rs4920291:18293760:T:C             586   25
rs223177:18579038:C:A             1416   25
etc...
```

When I do `na.omit` to remove NAs, I don't get a square matrix. The dimensions are not equal.

```r
LD_matrix <- na.omit(matrix)

[1] 5695 5777
```

So its removed the 82 rows with NAs from the rows but not the columns.

So the dimensions should be

```r
[1] 5695 5695
```

Any idea how to remove NAs from the whole matrix but it results in a square matrix rather than a rectangle with unequal dim?

Comment: The standard way to remove `NA`s from a matrix or data frame (the one that `na.omit` does) is to look at a row, if there are any `NA` values, remove the row. If you want something else, you'll have to specify what. Maybe on a simple example instead of one with thousands of rows and columns. Like, if your input was `m = matrix(c(1:6, NA, NA, NA), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)` what output would you want?

Comment: If the matrix is to remain square, then I see two obvious choices.
(i) Replace NA by some value.
(ii) Delete both row and column of the NA value.

Comment: Deleting all columns and rows containing NA's will not necessarily lead to a square matrix. E.g. you have two NA's in the same column, they are obviously not in the same row. Thus, you are deleting an unequal number of cols and rows

Answer (score 0):

The sample code below may be useful:

##### 1. Create sample matrix that contains NAs

run:

```
sample_matrix <- matrix(sample(c(1, NA), 
              size = 100, 
              replace = TRUE),
       nrow = 10,
       ncol = 10)
```

You will get a 10 by 10 matrix looks similar to this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    NA
 [2,]   NA    1    1    1   NA    1    1   NA   NA     1
 [3,]   NA   NA    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA    1     1
 [4,]   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA    NA
 [5,]   NA   NA    1    1   NA    1   NA    1   NA     1
 [6,]    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA   NA    NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA    1   NA     1
 [8,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA    1    NA
 [9,]    1   NA   NA    1    1   NA   NA   NA    1     1
[10,]    1   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    NA
```

##### 2. Change NAs to your desired value:

Here, I changed all NAs to 1:

```
sample_matrix[is.na(sample_matrix)] <- 1
```

##### 3. Inspect the outcome:

run `sample_matrix` again, you will see a new matrix with the same dimension (10 by 10 in this case), but all NAs are changed to your desired value:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

Hope it makes sense, let me know if it's not clear.